# what is the difference when we initialize a string variable as null or empty string in javascript? Which is prefered

Tags: javascript, string, initialization

What is the best way to initialize a string in javascript?

```
var s = "" 
var s = null
```

What is the difference between the above two?

Comment: If you are are going to call string methods on `s` it's better if `s` is a string. For example,  if `s` is  `null` this is an error: `s.substring(0, 0)` and you would need to check `s` before calling, which may not be the behavior you want.

Comment: If you set to null you can not call any method of string but with “” you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you intended the value future values are `Strings` so it's always better to use `empty string` as initial value, in your code than you need not to check before applying any of [**string related method**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) otherwise you need to add a check every time you use string method on variable

```js
let str = ''

console.log(str.replace(/.*/g , 'Hello'))

let noStr = null

console.log(noStr.replace(/.*/g , 'Hello'))
```